# Find latest .bak file in directory and zip it

Tags: powershell

I am curious on how to use PowerShell to find a latest `.bak` file in a directory and zip it.

I have been able to find the latest backup by using:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\* -Include *.bak
```

but I am having issues zipping the file it finds. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you're using PowerShell v5+ there's a new cmdlet called `Compress-Archive`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sort` and `Select` are your friends here, then pipe to `Compress-Archive` (only available with PS v5 onwards)

```
$source = "C:\"
$filetype = "bak"

Get-ChildItem "$source\*" -Include "*.$filetype" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$source\latest_backup.zip"
```

---

**EDIT:**

To use the name of the file for the zip:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem "$source\*" -Include "*.$filetype" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
Compress-Archive -Path $file -DestinationPath "$source\$($file.BaseName).zip"
```

Comment: Hello James, is there a way to have it take the name of the file it found and have it be the name, instead of having to create the name in the script?

Comment: Thanks James. Been fiddling around with it and figured it out!